# math operation in list of list

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have created 1000 lists containing some values. I wanted to have a math operation on elements of each list and saving in another list that I want to plot. Each list has the shape like below and I want to subtract the ith element from the i-1th element(distance between two consecutive elements)

```
[[   4   29   73  111  130  140  167  231  248  267  284  298  320  333
   379  404  421  433  475  510  523  534  544  558  575  602  617  630
   661  672  685  698  711  731  742  764  780  828  842  854  874  885
   903  916  944  961  985  996 1013 1032 1054 1064 1077 1109 1122 1138
  1205 1233 1249 1282 1299 1311 1326 1337 1372 1409 1426 1437 1511 1549
  1578 1591 1604 1646]]
```

I have written the code below but it does not work and I got the error of index out of range.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

Cases = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('config')]
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
maxnum = np.max([int(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('_')[1]) for f in CASES])
CASES = ['configuration_%d.out' % i for i in range(maxnum)]
gg = []
my_l_h = []

for i, d in enumerate(CASES):
    a = np.loadtxt(d).T
    x = a[3]
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance=10)

    gg = [peaks]

L_h = np.array(gg)
for numbers in gg:
    jp = L_h[:,i]-L_h[:,i-1]
    my_l_h.append(jp)
    print(my_l_h)
t = np.arange(0,len(my_l_h)
plt.plot(t,my_l_h)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The code looks a bit strange. Here you're putting peaks into gg everytime, which keeps overwriting the previous peak value. Do you mean to use gg.append(peaks)?

Comment: @Mercury yes it is.

Comment: @Mercury but the problem with `append` is the type. The command does not work for this case.